# Hide or display links on view depending on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So on my MVC application I want to display a link in the view, which when clicked allows a set of links to appear on screen through the following code:

```
<ul class="productmenu">
   @foreach (ProductCategoryRecord pc in Model.ProductCategories)
   {
      <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Store", new { id = pc.Name })">@pc.Name</a></li>
   }

   @if (Model.ProductCategories.Count() <= 0)
   {
      <p>There are no products in this category</p>
   }
</ul>
```

So how would I enable/disable this code from the view using a link 'More' which when clicked will change to 'Less(and display the links) and when clicked again will change 'less' back to 'more'(and hide the links)

Something like....`<li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Store", new { id = string.Empty })">More</a></li>`

Only i dont need to go back to the controller for this, so JS or something I am guessing??
thanks for any help

So iv gotten it working but I need the 'show products' text to appear to 'hide products's when it is clicked..

```
 <li id="showProductCategories" class="showProductCategories">
           <a>Show Products</a>
        </li>
  </ul>

     <div id="productLink">
          <ul class="categorymenu">
             @foreach (ProductCategoryRecord pc in Model.ProductCategories)
             {
                 <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Store", new { id = pc.Name })">@pc.Name</a></li>
             }

             @if (Model.ProductCategories.Count() <= 0)
             {
                  <p>There are no products in this category</p>
             }
          </ul>
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $('#showProductCategories').click(function () {
             $('#productLink').toggle('slow', function () {

             });
         });
     </Script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do some research, you may start here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  var $container = $(document.getElementById('container')),
      $categories = $container.find('.categorymenu'),
      $toggle = $container.find('#toggleProductCategories'),
      minEntries = 1 // amount of entries to show by default
  ;

  minEntries -= 1;

  $('li', $categories).filter(':gt('+minEntries+')').hide();

  $toggle.click(function (event) {

    $('li', $categories).filter(':gt('+minEntries+')').toggle('slow');

    $toggle.html(function(i, html) {
      return html === 'Less' ? 'More' : 'Less';
    });

    event.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

See example @ http://jsbin.com/ejaniz/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="productLink">
      <ul class="categorymenu">
         @foreach (ProductCategoryRecord pc in Model.ProductCategories)
         {
             <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Store", new { id = pc.Name })">@pc.Name</a></li>
         }

         @if (Model.ProductCategories.Count() <= 0)
         {
              <p>There are no products in this category</p>
         }
      </ul>
    <div id="showHideButtons">
        <span class="toggleLink">Hide</sapn>
        <span class="toggleLink">Show</sapn>
    </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $('#showHideButtons').click(function () {
        $('.categorymenu').slideToggle();
        $('.toggleLink').toggle();
         });
     });
 </Script>
```